# How to make the neon effect glow outside the black background with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm modifying a Shopify template but my CSS knowledge is limited and I'm stuck with this problem for hours already.

1. When I put `margin: 3rem 0;` in `.slick-slider`, it works but whenever the page loads, the card stacks jump to new positions.
2. When I put `margin: 3rem 0;` in `.featured-products`, the card stacks stay in their positions but the glow is stopped like the first photo. Also, the titles disappear when I put `top: -30px;` into `.widget-title`.

I really appreciate if you could show me how to make it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for padding, not margin.

I navigated to your sign and used the login credentials you provided, added some padding-top to the cards in the chrome dev tools, and the glow had more room at the top.

Specifically:

```
.grid-item {
    padding-top: 3rem;
}
```

Here, .grid-item refers to the children of .products-grid.